# What does these binary instructions represent

Tags: mips

I am trying to figure out what these binary numbers represent in all three formats (R, I, J). Here is the number I am given, can somebody explain what these actually are asking because I am a little confused. So for example, I think the first R-Type is adding $S0 + $S0 = $S0 but I am not too sure. Any help?

```
0000 0010 0001 0000 1000 0000 0010 0000

R-Type: OP = 0  RS = 16  RT = 16  RD = 16  SHAMT = 0  FUNC = 32

I-Type: OP = 0  RS = 16  RT = 16  Immediate = 32,800

J-Type: OP = 0  Address = (it's up in the millions so I don't think I did this correct)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [this page](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MIPS_Assembly/Instruction_Formats#Opcodes), order by OPCODE. You'll see that none of the I-type and J-type opcodes are zero.

From here, you can make the assumption that you're dealing with a R-type instruction, partition the bits into how the R-type format looks, and convert using the [MIPS green sheet](http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61c/resources/MIPS_Green_Sheet.pdf).